# Python: Log in a website using urllib, how do I check login successful?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to log in to this website: https://www.netflix.com/login. I'm having trouble with verifying if the login is successful or not. I tried using if...in.. condition but it still doesn't work, so i commented it out. This is my code I use:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar
import re
#creating a opener that that will allow us to open webpage
#and save all session and cookie information in the jar

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

res = opener.open('https://www.netflix.com/Login')
data = res.read()
results = re.search('name="authURL".*?value="(?P<authURL>.*?)"', data)
authURL = results.group('authURL')

formValues = {
    "email" : "***********",
    "password" : "*****",
    'authURL': authURL
}

#encode these value so python can subbmit in http request
#so server can udnerstand

data = urllib.urlencode(formValues)

response = opener.open("https://www.netflix.com/Login?locale=en-US", data)

#m = re.search('Sorry, we are unable to process your request. Please try again later.', response.read())
#if m:
#       print "Log in failed!"

#if 'signup' in response.url:
#    print "Login failed.  Not sure why"
```